# Centrifuge + React

Tags: reactjs, centrifuge

In our app we use centrifuge as a web socket connection + react.
When it is time to refresh token, I use config function - onRefresh, then I receive new token and set it.

```
refreshHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("act")}` },
  onRefresh: async function (ctx, cb) {
    try {
      await axios
        .post(`${BASE_URL}/centrifugo/refresh`, null, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("act")}`,
          },
        })
        .then((data) => {
          centrifuge.setToken(data.token);
        });
    } catch {
      centrifuge.disconnect();
      console.log("resfresh failed 1");
    }
  },
```

But in ws connection I got an error - code:109, token expired
What is wrong in my way?

Answer (score 0):

For centrifuge-js v2.x for which this question was asked for - the solution is to call `cb` (passed by SDK in `onRefresh` arguments) instead of `centrifuge.setToken` when token is obtained from the backend.

centrifuge-js v3.x has slightly different API for token refresh, [described here](https://centrifugal.dev/docs/transports/client_api)